No way to add a 'before hook' custom filter depending on an array in AdminJS
What's the problem?
I want to add a before hook on the list action that can pre filter my list of records depending on an array.
In the following example I want to pre filter the list of users depending on if their id is in a list of ids.
I'm using fastify as a server and typeORM for my database.
the '$in' operator seems not to be supported and always returns error like 'Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'type')'
I also tried to do custom filter but there is no way to actual create a new Filter and use it inside adminJS hook function.
There is a similar issue opened with no response : https://github.com/SoftwareBrothers/adminjs/issues/1564
Relevant code
export const filter = async (request: ActionRequest, context: ActionContext) => {
  const { query = {} } = request;
  const { currentAdmin } = context;

  // If the current user is admin, do not filter
  if (currentAdmin.role === Role.Admin) {
    return request;
  } else {
    // For non-admin users, find associated centers
    const userRepository = datasource.getRepository(User);
    const connectedUser = await userRepository.findOne({
      where: { email: currentAdmin.email },
    });
    if(connectedUser) {

      const prescriptionIds = ['id1', 'id2', 'id3'];
  
      const newQuery = {
        ...query,
        filters: {
          ...query.filters,
          id: { $in: prescriptionIds }, // <--- Here is the problem
        },
      };
  
      request.query = newQuery;
      return request;
    }
  }
};

AdminJS dependencies version
"@adminjs/design-system": "^4.1.1",
"@adminjs/fastify": "^4.1.0",
"@adminjs/relations": "^1.1.2",
"@adminjs/themes": "^1.0.1",
"@adminjs/typeorm": "^5.0.0",

Relevant log output
"res":{"statusCode":500},"err":{"type":"TypeError","message":"Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'type')","stack":"TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'type')\n    at Object.isParserForType (file://node_modules/@adminjs/typeorm/lib/utils/filter/date-filter.parser.js:3:80)\n    at file://node_modules/@adminjs/typeorm/lib/utils/filter/filter.converter.js:10:46\n    at Array.find (<anonymous>)\n    at file://node_modules/@adminjs/typeorm/lib/utils/filter/filter.converter.js:10:32\n    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)\n    at convertFilter (file://node_modules/@adminjs/typeorm/lib/utils/filter/filter.converter.js:9:35)\n    at Resource.find (file://node_modules/@adminjs/typeorm/lib/Resource.js:48:20)\n    at Object.handler (file://node_modules/adminjs/lib/backend/actions/list/list-action.js:66:36)\n    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)"},"msg":"Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'type')"}

I tried using the $in operator as long as creating a new Filter, but adminJS is not accepting custom filters.
